# Postgres order by clause returning out of sequence number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this postgres sql query:

```
select Symbol,Date,Year,DayofYear Close 
from DailyPricesAMEX 
where symbol = IBM 
order by DayofYear DESC;
```

The output from the query is:

```
Symbol  Year  DayofYear
IBM     2014  99
IBM     2014  98
IBM     2014  97
IBM     2014  9
IBM     2014  89
IBM     2014  88
```

What I want returned is:

```
Symbol  Year  DayofYear
IBM     2014  99
IBM     2014  98
IBM     2014  97
IBM     2014  89
IBM     2014  88
IBM     2014  9
```

I'm stuck, anyone got any ideas.

Comment: Never, ever store numbers as strings. Just don't. The problem you have stems directly from that design mistake. Change the column to a proper number (e.g. `integer`) and you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me like `DayofYear` is saved as a `VARCHAR`. Try following:

```
select Symbol,Date,Year,DayofYear Close 
from DailyPricesAMEX 
where symbol = IBM 
order by DayofYear::integer DESC;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/40a2f/2

---

**HINT**:
it would be better to change the type of your column to integer. Therefore you can use the following:

```
ALTER TABLE DailyPricesAMEX ALTER COLUMN DayofYear TYPE integer USING (DayofYear::integer);
```